# Physical significance of circuit eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, eigenvalue, linear-systems

When solving a DC circuit (say, with resistors and voltage sources only), we can use Kirchhoff's laws to get a set of equations in the currents:
$$
RI=V,
$$
where $R$ is a matrix relating to the resistance, $I$ is a vector containing the currents, and $V$ a vector containing the sum of voltages in the Kirchhoff-loop.

Is there some Physical interpretation for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the resistance matrix? Does this interpretation generalize to $RLC$ circuits using an impedance matrix?

Answer (score 0):

In a DC circuit, one generally provides the resistance matrix and voltages, from which the currents are calculated via Kirchoff's laws and Ohm's law:

$$I=R^{-1} V$$

Keep in mind that the eigenvectors of $R^{-1}$ are the same as $R$, but with inverse eigenvalue (assuming it is nonzero).

$$Rv=\lambda v \implies R^{-1}v = \frac{1}{\lambda}v$$

With this interpretation in mind, the eigenvectors of $R$ would correspond to those configurations of $V$ for which the resulting current-vector is simply proportional to the voltage-vector, $I=R^{-1}V\propto V$.

I can't think of any usage of this, especially since one is not always free to adjust the voltages $V$ exactly how you want. When one is solving for $n$ unknown currents, generally there are far less independent voltage currents. The linearly independent equations are derived from Kirchoff's laws. Therefore it may be that by adjusting your independent voltage sources, you may never even be able to land in the eigenspace of $R$.